# Windows messes up data put in TextBox Control

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

This is unbelievable to me, and I do not know how to work around this problem!
I try to put `[4]0.004` into an EditBox Control and what appears in the EditBox is `0.004[4]`.  Same result is obtained with parenthesis and braces.  Then with `-4-0.004` I get `4-0.004-`.  Here is simplified code that reproducers the problem:

```
void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CString test = _T("[4]0.004");
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_TX_CELL_MAX_V, test);
}
```

The EditBox control is defined in the .rc file as:

```
    EDITTEXT        IDC_TX_CELL_MAX_V,100,121,58,15,ES_CENTER | ES_READONLY | NOT WS_BORDER,WS_EX_RTLREADING | WS_EX_STATICEDGE
```

And Here is the image on the screen:

[image]

How do I work around this problem?

Comment: What's the rationale behind using the `WS_EX_RTLREADING` [extended window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles)?

Comment: No special rationale, It seems to have been selected automatically by the dialog editor in VS2013. Ah, That flag is actually causing the transposition of portions of my text. Good catch, that was the problem.  I wonder why it is the default when you place an edit box control.

Comment: Well, remove it then. You don't seem to be interested in using right-to-left text display, so specifying right-to-left text is at best ignored.

Comment: Now I need to find out why VS2013 is automatically selecting that flag when I place my controls.  I recently moved to using a new computer that was installed with Chinese Windows that was converted to English, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: If the PC (Windows) is set up for RtoL, that would explain why VS is honoring that as the default behavior.  (This won't be your only issue with your PC if it was Chinese Windows converted to English.)

Comment: @Tomasz, What language did you select for the resources? If it is Polish WS_EX_RTLREADING should not be inserted automatically.

Comment: The language is English.  Also it was the base (initial release of VS2013), since then I installed service pack 5 for VS2013 and the problem is not there anymore. Thanks all for your answers and suggestions.

Comment: @Tomasz Just to make sure and confirm. I am referring to the RESOURCE language.
Click on the dialog in the resource view and select 'properties'. This should show the language used by the dialog resource. Are you referring to the same?

Comment: Yes in the Dialog Resource the Language is English (United States) - and was by default (I never changed it).  This must have been some kind of bug in the initial release of VS2013 as before the Service Pack 5 install it would select right to left for Edit Box, but after SP5 does not happen anymore.

Comment: The project I initially created with VS2013 on my previous laptop Win8.1 under VS2013SP5, then I got the new laptop which was purchased with pre-configured Chinese Traditional Windows which I then had converted to English(US), I then installed VS2013 (Initial release) which I had a CD image for, but forgot to install the service pack. That is where the problem started to appear for new Edit Box controls added to the project.